# JPA (hibernate) does not insert on persist, needs to be flushed

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I have a stateless bean that observes an event and saves a record:

```
@Stateless
public class Manager {
    @Inject
    Repository repository;

    Manager() {}

    @Inject
    Manager(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void EventHandler(@Observes MyEvent myEvent) {
        save(event.obj);
    }

    private save(Object object) {
        repository.add(object);
    }
}
```

My repository is like this:

```
@Stateless
public class Repository {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    Repository() {}

    public void add(Object object) {
        em.persist(object);
        // em.flush();  <---
    }
}
```

**It doesn’t work unless I uncomment the line**
The thing I don’t understand is why do I need to flush! Shouldn’t the transaction commit automatically?

Could it be that I have an EJB container and the cdi transaction started by Observes never actually ends but do something weird? Or it ends but doesn’t commit because he doesn’t know about EJB?

Comment: You're probably rollbacking the transaction later. Any exception?

Comment: Mmmm interesting point. I don't see it rolled back in the log but there's a small chance someone is gulping that exception... I may have to investigate on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`persist()` is not meant to insert the row immediately, but rather at flush time, which is usually immediately before transaction commit.

However, if this is not what you are asking, but the row is not inserted even after the transaction has ended, it may be that flush mode for that transaction is set to [manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html).

Comment: I'm not using anything hibernate specific exactly because I wanted to avoid reading this kind of non portable documentation.